# How to setup PhpStorm Live Edit with SASS?

Tags: css, intellij-idea, sass, phpstorm

I am having a trouble setting up PhpStorm IDE for my needs.
I have a Wordpress project with .scss files deployed on ftp server, not locally.

In "General settings", I have turned on "Synchronize files on frame activation" and "Save files on frame deactivation".
In "Deployment options" "Upload external changes" is checked too.

File watcher for .scss files configuration is shown here:

[.SCSS file watcher configuration PhpStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqIbU.png)

### Method 1 - works:

If I edit .scss files and press save, they compiles, then I <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to Google Chrome and reload the page - changes are deployed to server and visible.

### Desired method - not working:

I want to to edit files with Live Edit turned on. But:

- In Live Edit "Immediate file synchronization" setting from file watcher is ignored and   whenever I type a letter, .scss files starts to compile immediately ("Trigger watcher regardless of syntax errors" is needed for SASS @at-root)
- Compiled css file is not synchronized from local file system to PhpStorm, because there is no <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (frame deactivation).
- No synchronization for css file = CSS is not deployed to FTP, only changed .scss file is deployed = Chrome doesn't show changes.

Tried to add keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to trigger PhpStorm "Reload in browser" and "Synchronize" - doesn't help.

Any help?

Comment: *"In Live Edit "Immediate file synchronization" setting from file watcher is ignored"* -- not really "ignored". It just has no effect ... as LiveEdit saves (or kind of saves) the file automatically .. which makes that option useless under such circumstance.

Comment: I also develop remotely and compile my CSS locally - I've found that fb-flo[1] allows my compiled CSS to be live-updated. I've also created a basic gruntfile[2] to get fb-flo running in a folder.


  [1]: http://facebook.github.io/fb-flo/
  [2]: https://gist.github.com/robert-bosweb/3d38572b257752a85320